# Use powershell to log into azure for an account that I am co-administrator for

Tags: powershell, azure

I have my own Azure account, which I can connect to quite happily using Windows Powershell, using microsoft account and password.  My client has an Azure account, which my microsoft account has been setup as an owner and co-administrator for, but when I login to Azure using Powershell Login-AzureRMAccount cmdlet and enter my microsoft credentials, I can only access my own azure account and not my clients.  How do I use powershell to login to my clients azure account?

Comment: Do you know your client TenantId? You could login like this `Login-AzureRMAccount -TenantId  <tenant id>`.

Comment: Or like `Add-AzureRmAccount -Tenant "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" -SubscriptionId "yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy"`

Comment: Does it work now?

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Login-AzureRmAccount**

To log into Azure Account

**Step 2: Get-AzureRmSubscription**

To list down all the Azure subscriptions associated with your account

**Step 3: Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription '*Subscription ID or Subscription Name*'**

To switch between Azure subscriptions.
Pass in the subscription ID or Subscription Name from Step 2 to switch to the required Azure subscription

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to No Refunds No Returns, this was the answer I was looking for.

Add-AzureRmAccount -Tenant "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" -SubscriptionId "yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy"